# Windows 7 boot manager ignores F8 key

Tags: windows-7, bootloader, bcd, bcdedit

I added a new entry to the bootloader using `bcdedit` for my Linux system (located on another partition), I also set the timeout to 10 seconds. It works perfectly and I can boot both Linux and Windows.

The problem is, I can either wait 10 seconds, or disable the timeout completely and always boot into Windows without being able to manually interrupt the boot process and select Linux instead - it ignores all my key presses, I tried ESC and F8, no reaction at all.

The bootloader's menu (with the Windows and Linux entries) briefly flashes for about half a second before booting into Windows, which it didn't do before (before it directly booted into Windows without flashing the entry list).

**How can I restore BCD's default behavior - stay totally hidden (no more 0,5 second flash with all the boot entries) and respond to F8 ?**

Output of `bcdedit /enum` (with English translations added - the OS is in French) :

```
Gestionnaire de démarrage Windows # Windows boot manager
---------------------------------
identificateur          {bootmgr}
device                  partition=C:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  fr-FR
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {be1fbe78-cca4-11e2-aff2-c5b6a4b0c8c0}
displayorder            {current}
                        {be1fbe7c-cca4-11e2-aff2-c5b6a4b0c8c0}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 0

Chargeur de démarrage Windows # Windows boot loader
-----------------------------
identificateur          {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  fr-FR
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {be1fbe7a-cca4-11e2-aff2-c5b6a4b0c8c0}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {be1fbe78-cca4-11e2-aff2-c5b6a4b0c8c0}
nx                      OptIn

Secteur de démarrage en mode réel # Real mode boot sector
---------------------------------
identificateur          {be1fbe7c-cca4-11e2-aff2-c5b6a4b0c8c0}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Linux.bin
description             Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a [custom bootstrap action](http://www.boyans.net/CustomActions.html) on another key like F2, F3, F4.... for Linux.

During POST type several times on specified F-key(should work even with small (0?) timeout).
There should be a small time interval between enabling keyboard in boot manager and menu display.

If keyboard in boot manager (bootmgr) is enabled only after boot menu display it is obvious that some small timeout should be specified for being able to intercept keyboard strokes.

The usual behavior on F8 key is to invoke advanced boot menu options for selected (default) Windows loader.

Comment: Note that you should remove all but the main Windows OS from the boot menu for this solution to work, otherwise the custom actions do not work. As soon as I removed the Linux entry from the boot menu both my custom action and the F8 key started working as expected (and the menu doesn't flash for half a second either which is nice).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `bcdedit /timeout 1` ?

Anyway, loader should wait for a while, to read your keypress, set it to 1-3 seconds.

Comment: That's what I currently have, but it adds one extra second to the boot process and displays an ugly list. What I would like is to have the default Windows 7 boot process while being able to manually select an OS by pressing F8.

Comment: @André Do you really care about one second? It can't read your keypress if not wait, and can't wait less than 1 second.

Comment: The real problem is the menu, I'd like to have a nice and clean boot screen like I always had.

Comment: @André what do you have now?

Comment: I have a timeout of one second, it's not ideal since it displays that ugly menu and delays the boot for one second, but I'm still looking to be able to restore its default behavior (no menu unless F8 is pressed).